# How to query select html made with javascript, and make more html?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a string of html with javascript and I am adding it to the dom. I want to select an element from that html string with a query selector so I can make another string of html in another if statement. When I try to do this the console says the selected element is null. Is it possible to select a javascript created html element? Here is the function with the code:

```
  function streams(){
if(this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
  if(this.status === 200){
    let data = JSON.parse(this.response);      
 const main = document.querySelector('.center-box');
 const desc = document.querySelector('.gamers');
if(data.logo){
      main.innerHTML += ` <div class ='gamers'>
<a href='${data.url}' target='blank'><img class='logo' src='${data.logo}'></a>
<h4 class='streamer'>${data.display_name}</h4>
</div>`;

}
    if(data.stream){
desc.innerHTML += `<p class='desc'></p>
<h6 class='online'>online</h6>`
} else {
desc.innerHTML += `
<h6 class='online'>offline</h6>`
 }
    console.log(data.stream)

  } 
}
}
```

I am trying to make the const desc select the class .gamers which is made by javascript under an if statement.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that attempts to select an element. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: oops. I forgot too add that, in my other code it is in the global scope. I am made the constant variable desc to select the class .gamers, which I made from javascript under my if statement. I have another if statement if(data.stream) that I want to use disc under. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Either `main` or `desc` could be `null` because `document.querySelector` did not find anything. If that is the case, then when you write `main.innerHtml` it's the equivalent of typing `null.innerHtml` and you will get a TypeError.

I would double check your DOM and make sure that elements with those classes exist. Good luck!

Comment: main exists, it is a query selector for an html element I made on my html page. and the html string under the if statement with main.innerHTML += is showing up in my dom, but when I try to select the .gamers class from the html string in my javascript, I get null.

Comment: So it sounds like `desc` is null... does your DOM contain an element with a gamers class? That could be your issue